# rapidJson: crashed in release mode

Tags: crash, release, rapidjson

I used `rapidJson` to read json data. I can build my application in both Debug and Release mode, but the application crashes in Release mode.

```
    using namespace rapidjson;
    ...
    char *buffer;
    long fileSize;
    size_t fileReadingResult;

    //obtain file size
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(pFile);
    if (fileSize <= 0) return false;
    rewind(pFile);

    //allocate memory to contain the whole file
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) return false;

    //copy the file into the buffer
    fileReadingResult = fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, pFile);
    if (fileReadingResult != fileSize) return false;
    buffer[fileSize] = 0;

    Document document;
    document.Parse(buffer);
```

When I run it in Release mode, I encounter an `Unhanded exception; A heap has been corrupted`.
The application breaks at `"res = _heap_alloc(size)` in `malloc.c` file

```
void * __cdecl _malloc_base (size_t size)
{
     void *res = NULL;

//  validate size
if (size <= _HEAP_MAXREQ) {
    for (;;) {

        //  allocate memory block
        res = _heap_alloc(size);

        //  if successful allocation, return pointer to memory
        //  if new handling turned off altogether, return NULL

        if (res != NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (_newmode == 0)
        {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            break;
        }

        //  call installed new handler
        if (!_callnewh(size))
            break;

        //  new handler was successful -- try to allocate again
    }
```

It runs fine in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a `memory leak` issue with your `Malloc` since it runs fine one time in Debug, but when you keep the application up longer it crashes.

Do you `free` your `buffer` after using it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. You allocate a buffer of `fileSize` bytes but after reading the file, you write at the fileSize+1-th position with `buffer[fileSize] = 0;`

Fix: change allocation with one larger.

```
buffer = (char *)malloc(fileSize + 1);
```

Debug builds pad memory allocations with additional bytes so it does not crash.